# Angular2: Scope between component and services?

Tags: variables, angular, typescript, scope, angular2-services

I'm developing a large Angular2 application. The application contains a lot of components with similar behaviour. Following the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle I have contained all common component functionality in a shared service.

However, for most components (e.g. foo.component.ts) I have a corresponsing "personal" service that fetches data for the specific component (e.g. foo.service.ts). To sum up all components make use of 2 services, they're own unique service and a shared one. The code for the "personal" service looks like this:

```
export class MasterDataService {
  getData(param) {
    return this._http.get("some/url/"+param+"/)
      .map((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
  }
}
```

Currently, my components use the shared service in order to fetch data. The way I do this now is by calling a function in the shared service and sending the "personal" service as a paramter to that function:

```
public initializeController(dataService, component:any) {
    this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      (param: any) => {
        this._param = param;

        dataService.getData(param).subscribe(
          data => this._httpSuccess(data, component),
          err => this._httpError(err)
        );

      }
    );
  }
```

In the same function I also send my component as a parameter:

```
// In component
   this._controller.initializeController(this);
```

The reason for this is that I have a dataModel in my component that includes the data for my HTML. The generic shared service is in charge of calling a personal service, and updating the dataModel in my component.

```
setLocalData(data) {
    console.log("Callback fired!!");
    this.masterdataModel = data;
    this.loading = false;
  }

this.dataModel = {
      data_1: "foo",
      data_2: "bar",
    };
```

I have found a solution that works, when setting my model data in my component through my shared service by sending "this" as a paramter from my component to my service function:

```
// In component
this._controller.initializeController(this);

// In service
public initializeController(component:any) {

    component.dataModel = {/* some new data */}
}
```

I send the personal service and the component as a paramter because I cannot access the callback function or the personal service from the shared service in any other way.

**Question 1:** How do I structure this generic service or function that can call function from a "personal" service that each component has? Am I doing it in a correct manner or is there a much better way?

**Question 2:** How does my component call a service function or set a component callback or access a variable in my component from my service?

**Question 3:** The reason why I find this very dificult is because I am using "=>" to switch context of "this" in my shared service, which is why I ended up sending my component as a parameter. What solutions are there for this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can provide the "personal service" at the component, then each component instance gets its own service instance (not sure if this is what you want)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  providers: [MyComponentPersonalService]
  ...
})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private personalService:MyComponentPersonalService) {}
```

**Question 1:** I suggest you make a method in the shared service that returns an `Observable` and the personal service subscribes to that observable and executes what's necessary when the shared service emits a value.

**Question 2:** Same as Question 1

**Question 3:** passing references around this way is quite weird and should be avoided at all

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service for examples with observables.